# Stuck at step 4 in migration from SQL Server to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, migration, azure-data-studio

I'm new to Azure service and I just tried migrating my SQL Server database to Azure. I follow this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-azure-sql-database-offline-ads

The tutorial's step 4 is shown here:

[image]

However, my step 4 is different. I've successfully connected to Azure and it shows my database as seen here:

[image]

When I click next I see this:

[image]

What's Azure Data Migration service? I tried to create a new one but it won't let me.

[image]

What should I be doing next? I can't find an online guide on this specific part. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you followed the link in the error message? https://aka.ms/rps-not-found

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to migrate the SQL database from on premises to Azure SQL, I got the same issue as well.

In order to fix this, you need to go to the subscription tab in azure portal and check for the `Microsoft.DataMigration`  provider. If it is not registered, select the same and click on register tab as highlighted in the screenshot below:

[image]

You will be able to see the message as in the below screenshot after the service is registered successfully.

[image]

[image]

After registering I was able to migrate my database without any error.